# Firebase rules: is it possible to communicate between security rules of different products

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I understand that I can specify rules for some features in firebase like `real-time database` and `firebase storage`.

**Example:**

I can specify a rule in real time database that allows only users to update their data under their specific UID.

**Question:**

Is it possible to specify a rule in firebase storage such that a user can download a file (ex: image) if and only if he exists under a certain node in the real time database?

Is this communication between security rules of different products possible?

If no, what can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't communicate between products like this.

What you can do instead is use custom claims on authenticated user profiles to control who can access what locations in various products.

[Read more about custom claims here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

[Read more about realtime database rules with custom claims.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-custom)  [Read about auth.token.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken)

[In Firestore, you can use request.auth.token to access custom claims.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth)

[In Cloud Storage, you can also use request.auth.token.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security#user_authentication)

Comment: And where do I create this custom claim?

Comment: The first link gives you lots of options.

Comment: Is it something that can be set from the console for any uid?

Comment: No, you write code as shown in the examples on that page.

Comment: What I understand is that you need to do custom authentication? If that is the case then while you do custom authentication you have to set the custom claim as a flag that is returned when an auth is returned to the client........now what I don't understand is how that will help me for example allow a user to download an image if he exists under (users node) in the real time database?

Comment: No, you can use custom claims with any provider in Firebase Authentication.  All you need to know is the user's uid, and you can use the admin SDK to make changes to their claims.

Comment: ahh but how to let the claim know that a user should exist under a certain node?

Comment: That's not what you use a claim for.  They're just properties on the user that you can use in rules to determine who can access what.

Comment: Or whatever your backend is.

Comment: So when someone authenticate, I run a function, check if his/her uid exist in a certain node, and then provide them with a flag (or a claim)? This is the process?

Comment: You're gonna have to design it whatever way works for your system.  I can't tell you the best way to do that because I don't know how it's supposed to work, and there's not enough room here to explore that.

Comment: yeah I know, but just to understand, a claim is simply a property returned after a user authenticates with a certain provider.......If I used cloud functions.....I run the function at the moment authentication occurs?

Comment: Or whenever you want a user to have that claim. You decide when that is.